# Facebook iOS SDK request permission publish_actions, but user need to input password again

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions, facebook-login, facebook-permissions

Facebook iOS SDK 3.8 was used in my project, and now I upgrade it to 3.22.

A weird thing occurred during requesting "publish_actions" permission, which is the user need to input her account&password again. While in the previous version the part "login again" will just be skipped. I want to know if the logic in Facebook SDK changes, or I have to change the session handling process. Any ideas on this problem?

The way I used to request the "publish_actions" permission is:

```
 [activeSession openWithBehavior: FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView
        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                            FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
    [session reauthorizeWithPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                                                        isRead:NO
                                                                      behavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView
                                                               defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
 }
```

And I also tried

```
[FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                          defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                        __block NSString *alertText;
                                        __block NSString *alertTitle;
                                        _reauthorizeInProgress = YES;
                                        if (!error) {
                                            if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions
                                                 indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound){
                                                // Permission not granted, tell the user we will not publish
                                                alertTitle = @"Permission not granted";
                                                alertText = @"Your action will not be published to Facebook.";
                                                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                                                            message:alertText
                                                                           delegate:self
                                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                                            } else {
                                                // Permission granted, publish the OG story

                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            // There was an error, handle it
                                            // See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
                                        }
                                    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is the default set by Facebook. The document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2  says that:

> The Disadvantage of WebView is:
>
> People have to fill in their login credentials every time they go through the login flow.

In the FBSession.m file, I change the code in method

```
- (void)retryableAuthorizeWithPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
                      defaultAudience:(FBSessionDefaultAudience)defaultAudience
                       integratedAuth:(BOOL)tryIntegratedAuth
                            FBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth
                           safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth
                             fallback:(BOOL)tryFallback
                        isReauthorize:(BOOL)isReauthorize
                  canFetchAppSettings:(BOOL)canFetchAppSettings
```

And do not delete cookie when asking for another permission, replace

```
   // To avoid surprises, delete any cookies we currently have.
    [FBUtility deleteFacebookCookies];
```

with

```
    // To avoid surprises, delete any cookies we currently have.
if(!isReauthorize){
    [FBUtility deleteFacebookCookies];
}
```

I agree that it is not a good idea to modify the SDK source, while I should make some balance between the consistence of user experience and the code style. ;(